# Set cutoff threshold when predicting in R

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

I'm trying different methods to classify a binary problem.

I'm using the command "predict" for basically every one, and confusionMatrix from the caret package to assess results, but I just can't find a way to specify the best cutoff threshold (which I've already found using roc and extracting the coords).

For example:
I know my best cutoff is 0.77, but I can't find a way to use it in the predict function, which uses 0.5 by default.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Do you mean that for example, the <= 0.7 has to be predicted as 0, and > 0,7 has to be predicted as 1?

Comment: Yep! I just found out that it can be done "easily" by using an ifelse on the result from predict(...probability=TRUE) to create a vector, transform it with as.factor, and using it inside confusionMatrix. I'd still like to know if there is an easier way to do it right inside the predict function, since it seems to me like it would be an useful feature...

Comment: Unluckily that's the only way I know and I currently use, as seen in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here something you can try if I've understood well:

```
# a model with a famous dataset
model <- glm(formula= vs ~ wt + disp, data=mtcars, family=binomial)

# let's predict the same data: use type response to have probability as resulthere you decide the cutoff and put as factor, in one line
pred_ <- as.factor(ifelse(predict(model, mtcars, type="response")>0.7,"1","0"))

# here we go!
confusionMatrix(pred_, as.factor(mtcars$vs))

    Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 16  3
         1  2 11

               Accuracy : 0.8438          
                 95% CI : (0.6721, 0.9472)
    No Information Rate : 0.5625          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.000738        

                  Kappa : 0.68            

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.000000        

            Sensitivity : 0.8889          
            Specificity : 0.7857          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.8421          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8462          
             Prevalence : 0.5625          
         Detection Rate : 0.5000          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5938          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.8373          

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

Comment: Well, I guess that is how it's done! I think it would be nice to have that feature baked into the predict function, but after all it's not that much of an hassle to do it this way. Thanks a lot s_t!